# Expectation of a function of Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I would like to how I can compute this expectation and get the answer that is given. All terms W indicate a Wiener process.

$$E_t[W_s^3]=E_t[(W_t+(W_s-W_t))^3]=W_t^3+3W_t(s-t)$$

Answer (score 3):

The first step is clear from $W_s = W_t + (W_s-W_t)$.

The second step comes from expanding the cubic expression and noting that $W_t$ is independent of $W_s-W_t$ (independent increments), as well as the fact that $W_s-W_t \sim N(0,(s-t))$.

\begin{align}
(W_t+(W_s-W_t))^3 &= W_t^3 + 3 W_t^2 (W_s-W_t) + 3 W_t (W_s-W_t)^2 + (W_s-W_t)^3\\
E_t[(W_t + (W_s-W_t))^3] &= E_t[W_t^3] + 3 E_t[W_t^2] E_t[W_s-W_t] + 3 E_t[W_t] E_t[(W_s-W_t)^2] + E_t[(W_s-W_t)^3]
\\
&= W_t^3 + 3 W_t^2 \cdot 0 + 3 W_t (s-t) + 0
\\
&= W_t^3 + 3 W_t (s-t).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, just one thing is unclear. How do you show that $$E_t[(W_s-W_t)^3]=0$$ ?

Comment: @Daniel Odd powers of Gaussian random variables are symmetric.

Comment: I misunderstood.